# How can I tell if I'm in beforeSave from an edit or a create? CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, model, callback, save, edit

I have a model where I need to do some processing before saving (or in certain cases with an edit) but not usually when simply editing.  In fact, if I do the processing on most edits, the resulting field will be wrong.  Right now, I am working in the beforeSave callback of the model.  How can I tell if I came from the edit or add?

Frank Luke

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
function beforeSave() {
  if (!$this->id && !isset($this->data[$this->alias][$this->primaryKey])) {
    // insert
  } else {
    // edit
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: A slightly better way to do it is rather than using the test '!isset', use the test 'empty'. That way, if the primary key field in the data array happens to exist, but be empty (as is sometimes the case when you share the add and edit view) then it still recognises it as saving a new record.

Comment: This does not work for me on cakephp3. For the Cakephp 3 version please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/25589117/1152756

Answer (score 9):

This is basically the same as neilcrookes' answer, except I'm using [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) as the test, as opposed to [`!isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

If an array key exists, but is empty, then !isset will return false, whereas empty will return true.

I like to use the same view file for add and edit, to keep my code DRY, meaning that when adding a record, the 'id' key will still be set, but will hold nothing. Cake handles this fine, except neilcrookes version of the code won't recognise it as an add, since the primaryKey key is set in the data array (even though it holds nothing). So, changing !isset to empty just accounts for that case.

```
function beforeSave() {
  if (!$this->id && empty($this->data[$this->alias][$this->primaryKey])) {
    // insert
  } else {
    // edit
  }
  return true;
}
```