# mysql add unique uuid to existing table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, qr-code, uuid

I have a table with primary key an auto incremental integer.
The table holds data of real world objects.

Now I want each row to have a uuid. I don't want to change the primary key. But I do want to be absolutely sure the assigned uuid doesn't get overwritten (So only create UUID on insert, not update)

I want to use this uuid as a QR code, so it needs be as unique to a record as the primary key is.

Any ideas how to do this?

(I'm using cakePHP2, so it might be behaviour like the created timestamp. This also only done with the original INSERT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Purely cake options**

There are many ways to do this...

The least code invasive I think, would be to add a check in `beforeSave` of the corresponding model, something like

```
public function beforeSave() {
    if (!$this->id && !isset($this->data[$this->alias][$this->primaryKey])) {
        // insert
        $this->data[$this->alias]['uuid'] = $this->createUUID();
    } else {
        // edit
        // if you don't want to do anything on insert, delete this "else"
    }
    return true;
}
```

(that code was copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751476/how-can-i-tell-if-im-in-beforesave-from-an-edit-or-a-create-cakephp)).

Now, you didn't provided much details as to what the uuid should be (integer, length, readable word...). But let's assume it's a simple integer, if it's not, all the changes needs to be done here. In the same model, add a function to create the uuid

```
private function createUUID() {
    do {
        $uuid = rand(); //any logic you want to create the uuid, a md5, substring, hash...
        //check for no repetition
        $help = $this->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('uuid'=>$uuid)));
    } while(!empty($help));
    return $uuid;
}
```

And that way, you'll have an unique uuid, only added on insert, without changing the rest of the code.
This is the solution I like.

Now, another way to do this, for example, would be to create the UUID function that returns a value, and using it in `afterSave` (check if it was an insert or an update) and do an update of the record with the uuid (you'll have the id of the new created record by then).

There's not much advantage of one versus the other... the `beforeSave`one allows you to set the uuid field in the database as NOT NULL, while if you use the `afterSave`, you need to insert the record first, and the uuid should be null for that.

Without much detail, I recommend the `beforeSave` option, just because I of the uuid NOT NULL thing.

Comment: thx. That's a good answer. One further step: how could I easily update the table (ie populate the newly added field)?

Comment: Instead of `rand()` you can use `String::uuid()` http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/string.html#String::uuid

Comment: @Costa yes, of course, that was just an example since I don't know the restrictions of the uuid, but great point. @Jeroen you could write a [shell function](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html) that basically calls `createUUID()` and edits every record that doesn't have an uuid. It could also be a function in the model or an action. If it's just this one time, the easiest option would do, since you won't use it any other time (and probably delete after using it). If it's a recurring thing (like once every month) consider shell script or controller action.

Comment: woudn't it be better to do unset($this->data[$this->alias]['uuid']) in the else-part of the beforeSave? to realy prevent accidental updates?

Comment: Sure (check with isset if the element exists first to avoid notices). What I posted wasn't a fully working example, you can add all the validations and functionality you need. I posted the skeleton of what I would do, but the details and everything else depends on what you consider useful and necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an insert trigger on the table to set a uuid using the mysql UUID() function.  You could the use a before update trigger to prevent the uuid from being changed (i.e. NEW.uuid=OLD.uuid in the trigger).