# cakephp3 how to check if entity is a newly inserted in afterSave callback?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Whenever an entity is inserted or updated, the afterSave callback is invoked. How do I check whether the entity is a newly inserted one?

Pseudo code of what I'm trying to do inside the afterSave callback.

```
if newly inserted {
    dispatch event using the events system;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have got the answer. The answer is as followed:

```
public function afterSave(Event $event, Entity $entity, array $options) {
    if ($entity->isNew()) {
        // do whatever you need to do here.
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone who's new to CakePHP 3.

Link here: http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Datasource.EntityInterface.html#_isNew